# How can I calculate an AIC value for a statsmodels linear mixed effects model?

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, mixed-models

The Statsmodels documentation page for the Linear Mixed Effects Model ([link](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/mixed_linear.html)) claims that "the statsmodels LME framework currently supports post-estimation inference via Wald tests and confidence intervals on the coefficients, profile likelihood analysis, likelihood ratio testing, and AIC."

I have tried to retrieve the AIC as follows:

```
model = smf.mixedlm(formula=formula,data=data_subset,groups=data_subset["m#"]).fit()
model.aic
```

But the resulting value is 'nan'.

I have also looked through the documentation for both mixedlm() & the mixedlm.fit() function but haven't been able to locate any arguments that would allow one to indicate that they wish to calculate an AIC.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You should use reml=False when you call model.fit().